# Can we have a build for windows with opencl enabled (FFmpeg)?

Tags: ffmpeg, opencl

Is it possible to have a build for Windows with open_cl enabled, please ?
Because this filter has an option (tonemap HDR video) not available elsewhere.

I mean, having the possibility to download the actual build available, and another with opencl enabled that allows the user to use dedicated filters, like "format=p010,hwupload,tonemap_opencl=t=bt2020:tonemap=linear:format=p010,hwdownload,format=p010" would be appreciated.

Thanks if it can be done.

Comment: I think you may be lost. Super User is not related to ffmpeg.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html
Here there's a link for superuser (at the end of the page)

Comment: Well, yes. Still, as they explicitly state there, "FFmpeg offers no official forum". SU is listed as a community where you can ask questions that may get answered by other users. Take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) if you want to learn what SU is about.

Comment: Ffmpeg doesn't make it clear, but that link is for support, not feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg only provides source code. The `ffmpeg.exe` that everyone uses is provided by [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), not FFmpeg. Hardware acceleration is not something I use, and I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure if it is possible to provide it with support for the `*_opencl` filters. So you'll have to ask Zeranoe.

The other option is to compile it yourself. Again, I'm not a Windows user, but a few build scripts seem popular from what I can tell:

- [ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers)
- [media-autobuild_suite](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite)
- [MultimediaTools-mingw-w64](https://github.com/Warblefly/MultimediaTools-mingw-w64)

Or see [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile/Windows](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide#Windows).